# console.log() is not print float number : javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem on the printing format of console.log().
I want to print floating point on console using JavaScript, such as `8.0`.
For example:

```
var i1 = 4.0;
var i2 = 8.0;

console.log(i1 + i2);
```

I want `12.0`, but `12` is printed.
I can fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: (i1 + i2).toFixed(1);

Comment: Javascript doesn't have integers, every JS number is a double precision floating point number. `12` is strictly equal to `12.0`, watch what happens when you print `i1` or `i2` it will just be `4` and `8` respectively. If you want to "see" the implicit `.0` on the end you need to convert to string.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

`console.log((i1 + i2).toFixed(1));`

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-format-a-number-with-two-decimals-in-JavaScript

> The toFixed() method formats a number with a specific number of digits
> to the right of the decimal. it returns a string representation of the
> number that does not use exponential notation and has the exact number
> of digits after the decimal place.

Comment: thank you. but it is have a problem. `3.3+5.55` is printed `8.8`. I want `8.85`

Comment: @BogdanBob: That would be `.toFixed(2)`, because there are *2* places after the decimal.  Or just remove the `.toFixed` call entirely in that case.

Comment: then use `toFixed(2)` ? You ought to decide and standardize your output formating!

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = i1 + i2;
console.log(sum.toFixed(1));
```

or you can print directly

```
console.log((i1+i2).toFixed(1))
```

you can also use toPrecision function. But then you have to send the number of digits you want to print.
Like for printing 4.0. if the i1 + i2 = 4

```
(a+b).toPrecision(2)
```